# Struct data type in Mathematica?

Tags: struct, types, wolfram-mathematica

After playing with Mathematica's symbolic and numerical capabilities, I find it to be a decent programming language, too. However, something making it less appealing as a general-purpose language is the lack of C-like struct data type (or the record type as known in Pascal). How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 15):

**Update**: Mathematica 10 has introduced [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html), which has many of the most important properties of a `struct`. (See [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33465106/330202).) The original, somewhat deprecated version of this answer is below.

---

You can use a *Mathematica* rule lists to mimic a C-like struct data type. E.g.,:

```
person = {firstName -> "John", lastName -> "Doe"}
```

You can then access the record's fields by using the `/.` operator:

```
firstName /. person
```

yields `John`.

```
lastName /. person
```

yields `Doe`.

To update a field of a record, prepend the updated field to the list:

```
PrependTo[person , firstName -> "Jane"]
```

`firstName /. person` then yields `Jane`.

Also see the *Mathematica* documentation on [transformation rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html).

Comment: Making a few changes using prepending means that a number of unused rules will appear in the person list. Not very efficient.

Comment: Note that Mathematica 10 has introduced [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html), which has many of the most important properties of a `struct`. See [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33465106/330202).

Comment: If a field in the "struct" is, say, a multidimensional array, is it possibly to modify individual components of that array with `PrependTo`?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Use [ReplacePart](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html), i.e. `PrependTo[struct, 
 "field" -> ReplacePart["field" /. struct, 2 -> 3.14]]`

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this. I hate to complain, but my first impression is that this is an awfully kludgy way of going about it. Why is it not possible to do a simple assignment like `lastName/.person="Smith"` should Jane Doe marry John Smith? Not your fault, I know!

Comment: Use [Associations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html). These let you do `struct["lastName"] = "Smith"`. This answer was written before they were introduced in Mathematica 10. Associations are pretty fast, as they are backed by a [HAMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie).

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply write things like this:

```
x[foo] = bar
x[bar] = baz
x[1] = 7
x[7] = 1
?x
```

Then to access the data for any specific index just type the same (e.g., `x[1]` will return `7`, `x[foo]` will return `bar`).

Comment: This way of doing things has one real advantage over the rule approach suggested by sakra: it allows you to mutate the "fields" of the "struct" in a straightforward way.

Comment: There's a problem with your answer: if a "field" is a list, its elements can't be changed individually. For example,
x[foo]={1,2};
x[foo] [[1]] =3 (* attempting to change list element *)
will result in an error, because x[foo] is not an Lvalue.
So it still doesn't fully replace C struct functionality.

Comment: You need to replace the old value completely, not just change a single value of the list: f["foo"] = {1, 2};
f["foo"] = (ReplacePart[f["foo"], 1 -> 3])  Also, I'd use strings or integers for keys, not symbols.  There's also some tricky business you can do by setting UpValues for Set.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica 10 has introduced [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html), which has many of the most important properties of a `struct`.

```
someData = <| "name" -> "Bob", "age" -> 23 |>

In[1]:= someData["name"]
Out[1]= Bob

In[2]:= someData["age"]
Out[2]= 23

In[3]:= someData[[2]]
Out[3]= 23
```

For more info, see

- [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)
- [`DataSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) (which builds on `Association`)
- Wolfram guides: [Elementary introduction to DataSets](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/45-datasets.html) and [Fast introduction for programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/associations/).
- Mathematica.SE questions: [How to make use of Associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations) and [Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica/993#993)
- [This HackerNews comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8012838).

Answer (score 2):

This way can work:

```
x[foo] = bar

x[bar] = baz

x[1] = 7

x[7] = 1

x[c] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

and also for changing the elements of a list field you can so the following:

```
x[c] = ReplacePart[x[c], {1, 1} -> 8]
```

which returns:

```
x[c] = {{8,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```